# Windows 7 password forgotten

Tags: windows-7

I have windows 7 installed on my system. this is my log-on screen. I forgot this account's password.

The question is, how I can log-in with another user? (Administrator) Why this windows has not **switch user** button?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Administrator` account is disabled by default in Windows Vista onwards. This is why you create an account when you first turn the computer on from new. Did you create a password reset disk? if not then you will need to use a reset tool like **Offline NT Password & Registry Editor** that can be put on a bootable CD or USB and you can blank or change your user account password. The Ultimate Boot CD (UBCD) has this tool.

**Be warned: Using any such software may result in irrecoverable data loss. Most times out of ten it works, however.**

Comment: I used windows-7 DVD disk and Command prompt in recovery section. I replace utilman.exe with cmd.exe and then I use net user command in log-in screen. as mentioned here : http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/reset-password-windows-7.htm

Comment: Yup, another solid workaround... :)

Comment: You mean my parents can get onto my computer?

Comment: If they know the tools and the ways to get at the OS then yes. The only way they can't is if you encrypt the drive and tell no-one the key.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why there is not a switch user button is because there is only one user

If you were to be able to access the account without knowing the password, as in *I forgot the password*, then what is the purpose of the password?

IIRC there is an Administrator account that may be dormant, and it may be possible to activate it in Safe Mode, but again, what then is the purpose of the password?

The only sure fire fix is to remove the hard disk, install a new hard disk, install Windows 7 and attach the old disk to the new installed win 7 and read your files into the new install.

Comment: This solution fixed my problem  : http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/reset-password-windows-7.htm